# collection sorting in baseadapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to sort my data in descending order and the logs seems to work but my BaseAdapter is not working.
I mean in the view the data is not sorted in descending order.
Here is my code in adapter -

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_object, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final MyData myData = getItem(position);


        sortDates.add(convertStringToDate(myData.getTimeBegin()));
        Collections.sort(sortDates, Collections.reverseOrder());

        bindView(holder, item);

        return convertView;
    }

     private Date convertStringToDate(final String dateString) {
        try {
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM. HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
            date = format.parse(dateString);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Where is the problem here?

Comment: use Comparable in your Class.

Comment: Date is already comparable